# Group by element in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Lets assume we have the following array

```
var arr = new string[] {"foo","bar","jar","\r","a","b,"c","\r","x","y","z","\r");
```

*Also ignore the fact that this is strings, so no string hack solutions please.*

I want to group these elements by each "\r" in the sequence.
That is, I want one array/enumerable with "foo","bar","jar" and another with "a","b","c" etc.

Is there anything in the ienumerable extensions that will let me do this or will I have to roll my own group by method here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I split an IEnumerable<String> into groups of IEnumerable<string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349491/how-can-i-split-an-ienumerablestring-into-groups-of-ienumerablestring)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate — the other one is asking for groups of fixed size, this one is asking for delimiter-based splitting.

Comment: @Timwi: *possible* being the keyword here....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote an extension method for this purpose which works on any `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Splits the specified IEnumerable at every element that satisfies a
/// specified predicate and returns a collection containing each sequence
/// of elements in between each pair of such elements. The elements
/// satisfying the predicate are not included.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="splitWhat">The collection to be split.</param>
/// <param name="splitWhere">A predicate that determines which elements
/// constitute the separators.</param>
/// <returns>A collection containing the individual pieces taken from the
/// original collection.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> splitWhat, Func<T, bool> splitWhere)
{
    if (splitWhat == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("splitWhat");
    if (splitWhere == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("splitWhere");
    return splitIterator(splitWhat, splitWhere);
}
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> splitIterator<T>(
        IEnumerable<T> splitWhat, Func<T, bool> splitWhere)
{
    int prevIndex = 0;
    foreach (var index in splitWhat
        .Select((elem, ind) => new { e = elem, i = ind })
        .Where(x => splitWhere(x.e)))
    {
        yield return splitWhat.Skip(prevIndex).Take(index.i - prevIndex);
        prevIndex = index.i + 1;
    }
    yield return splitWhat.Skip(prevIndex);
}
```

For example, in your case, you can use it like this:

```
var arr = new string[] { "foo", "bar", "jar", "\r", "a", "b", "c", "\r", "x", "y", "z", "\r" };
var results = arr.Split(elem => elem == "\r");

foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

This will print:

```
foo, bar, jar
a, b, c
x, y, z
```

(including a blank line at the end, because there is a `"\r"` at the end of your collection).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a standard `IEnumerable` extension method, you'd have to use `Aggregate` (but this is not as reusable as Timwi's solution):

```
var list = new[] { "foo","bar","jar","\r","a","b","c","\r","x","y","z","\r" };
var res = list.Aggregate(new List<List<string>>(),
                         (l, s) =>
                         {
                             if (s == "\r")
                             {
                                 l.Add(new List<string>());
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 if (!l.Any())
                                 {
                                     l.Add(new List<string>());
                                 }
                                 l.Last().Add(s);
                             }
                             return l;
                         });
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [nest yields to return IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> with lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452559/nest-yields-to-return-ienumerableienumerablet-with-lazy-evaluation) too. You can have a `SplitBy` extension method that accepts a predicate to split:

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> SplitBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                              Func<T, bool> separatorPredicate,
                                              bool includeEmptyEntries = false, 
                                              bool includeSeparators = false)
{
    var l = new List<T>();
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
        if (!separatorPredicate(x))
            l.Add(x);
        else
        {
            if (includeEmptyEntries || l.Count != 0)
            {
                if (includeSeparators)
                    l.Add(x);

                yield return l;
            }

            l = new List<T>();
        }
    }

    if (l.Count != 0)
        yield return l;
}
```

So in your case:

```
var arr = new string[] {"foo","bar","jar","\r","a","b,"c","\r","x","y","z","\r");
foreach (var items in arr.SplitBy(x => x == "\r"))
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
    }
```

Same as Timwi's, implemented differently. No error checking, thats upto u. This is going to be faster since you're traversing the list only once.