# Is there a "split list" method in c#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, list

In C#, calling the `.Split` method will split a string into an array of strings based on some character or string.

Is there an equivalent method for lists or arrays?

For example:

```
var foo = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 6 };
var output = Split(foo, 0);
// produces { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5 }, { 6 } }
```

This is what I have so far -- is there a cleaner or more eloquent way of accomplishing the same task?

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, T divider)
{
    var output = new List<List<T>>();
    var temp = new List<T>();
    foreach ( var item in list )
    {
        if (item.Equals(divider))
        {
            output.Add(temp);
            temp = new List<T>();
        }
        else
        {
            temp.Add(item);
        }
    }

    output.Add(temp);
    return output;
}
```

**Edit:**

It just occurred to me that my version will split the list only by a single element, whereas `string.Split` can split using either a single character, or an arbitrary string.

Just for the sake of completeness, what would be the best way to implement that?

Comment: You might be able to do something with IndexOf, though I'm not sure how that compares equality in general...

Comment: On your edit - while with single separator it is pretty straight forward what is "good/better" code, it is not the case for matching sequences: you'd need to properly handle misses during matching ( `aabbaba` split on `bab` requires some form of revisiting first `b` to return it) with different tradeoffs on multiple approaches to do so. There are also a lot of different string matching algorithms (which is exactly what you want in your edit) which optimize for different criteria. So edit is not really answerable (in sense of "the best").

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group by element in Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759123/group-by-element-in-linq)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No built-in equivalent, but a lazy-evaluated one would be

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, T divider)
{
    var temp = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (!item.Equals(divider))
        {
            temp.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return temp;
            temp = new List<T>();
        }
    }

    if(temp.Count>0) yield return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no special existing method in the framework to split sequence.

You code is reasonable.

Routes to improve/change:

- You may be able to use `yield return` instead of adding to `output` to gain some lazy evaluation.
- With even more interesting code you can make inner lists lazy too (which may be important if incoming sequence is not bound/too long segments).
- And you can using `Aggregate` if you want to show off single statement code...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of any built-in function. However, I would consider doing this:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<int>> Split(List<int> list, int delimiter)
{
    var start = 0;
    foreach (var end in list.FindAll(x => x == delimiter).Select(splitter => list.IndexOf(splitter, start)))
    {
        yield return list.GetRange(start, end - start);

        start = end + 1;
    }

    if (start <= list.Count)
    {
        yield return list.GetRange(start, list.Count - start);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure this is really an improvement over the Op's method ... it might be more readable, but it also requires (?) multiple passes over the input.

Comment: And it wouldn't work if the `list` is `IEnumerable<T>` not `List<T>` (because of *GetRange*)